# Using awk or sed to concatenate lines having a pattern

Tags: awk, sed, merge

I essentially want to put the name of the query in front of each line containing the SourceField.

I have tried this concatenation scheme

```
awk '/<\^Query/ && p{print p;p=""}{p=p $0}END{if(p) print p}'
```

But this only works until I have multiple source fields. When that happens it concatenates all the lines with SourceField:

```
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: LOAD-NO         SourceTable: MASTER SourceField: LO
```

My data is:

```
Query: D Monthly Loan
    SourceField: LOAD-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
    SourceField: LO              SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan
    SourceField: HI              SourceTable: MASTER2
QUERY: M FORBEARANCE_1
    SourceField: LOAN-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: LOAD-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: LO              SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: HI              SourceTable: MASTER2
Query: M FORBEARANCE_1 SourceField: LOAN-NO        SourceTable: MASTER
```

Comment: `<\^` at the start of `/<\^Query/` means "a literal `<` character followed by a literal `^` character". A string like that doesn't exist in your input. I **think** you just meant `/^Query/` which means "the string `Query` at the start of a line (`^`)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^ +/{print q, $0; next} {q=$0}' file
Query: D Monthly Loan     SourceField: LOAD-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan     SourceField: LO              SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan     SourceField: HI              SourceTable: MASTER2
QUERY: M FORBEARANCE_1     SourceField: LOAN-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
```

or if you prefer any of these formats (there are many other possibilities too!):

```
$ awk 'sub(/^ +/,""){print q, $0; next} {q=$0}' file
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: LOAD-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: LO              SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: HI              SourceTable: MASTER2
QUERY: M FORBEARANCE_1 SourceField: LOAN-NO         SourceTable: MASTER

$ awk '/^ +/{$1=$1; print q, $0; next} {q=$0}' file
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: LOAD-NO SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: LO SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: HI SourceTable: MASTER2
QUERY: M FORBEARANCE_1 SourceField: LOAN-NO SourceTable: MASTER

$ awk -v OFS='\t' '/^ +/{$1=$1; print q, $0; next} {q=$0}' file
Query: D Monthly Loan   SourceField:    LOAD-NO SourceTable:    MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan   SourceField:    LO      SourceTable:    MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan   SourceField:    HI      SourceTable:    MASTER2
QUERY: M FORBEARANCE_1  SourceField:    LOAN-NO SourceTable:    MASTER
```

Comment: Thanks for all the choices! I didn't realize at first that SourceField had a leading tab. So, of  course, absolutely none of anyone's solutions worked. Now they all work.But I like the simplicity of your first selection.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n -e '/^Query:\|^QUERY:/{h;}' -e '/^  *SourceField:/{G;s|\(.*\)\n\(.*\)|\2\1|p;}' file
```

- `/^Query:\|^QUERY:/{h;}` If line starts with `Query:`/`QUERY:`, put it in the hold space.
- `/  *SourceField:/` If line starts with any number of spaces followed by `SourceField:`, then:

  - `G` Append a the contents of the hold space preceeding it by a newline.
  - `s|\(.*\)\n\(.*\)|\2\1|p` Swap the fields around the newline and print the result.

Simplified version, in case your sed supports extended regexes:

```
sed -nE -e '/^Query:|^QUERY:/{h;}' -e '/^ +SourceField:/{G;s|(.*)\n(.*)|\2\1|p;}' file
```

Output:

```
Query: D Monthly Loan    SourceField: LOAD-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan    SourceField: LO              SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan    SourceField: HI              SourceTable: MASTER2
QUERY: M FORBEARANCE_1    SourceField: LOAN-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '/^Q/{query=$0; next}; /^ /{gsub(/^ */,"",$0); print query,$0}' file
```

Output:

```
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: LOAD-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: LO              SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan SourceField: HI              SourceTable: MASTER2
QUERY: M FORBEARANCE_1 SourceField: LOAN-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
```

`gsub(/^ */,"",$0)` removes leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
/^Query:/ || /^QUERY:/ {queryline=$0}
/ SourceField:/ {print queryline " " $0}
' data.txt
```

Comment: `/^Query:/ || /^QUERY:/` could be written as `tolower($0) ~ /^query:/` to avoid the duplication of uc and lc `query`. Also `print queryline " " $0` could be written as `print queryline, $0` to just let OFS do it's job.

Answer (score 1):

My solution will not take you all the way to your desired result but it's pretty simple but you can split your source with grep go from there:

```
# grep Source a|awk '{print "Query: D Monthly Loan" $0}'
Query: D Monthly Loan    SourceField: LOAD-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan    SourceField: LO              SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan    SourceField: HI              SourceTable: MASTER2
Query: D Monthly Loan    SourceField: LOAN-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
# cat a
Query: D Monthly Loan
    SourceField: LOAD-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
    SourceField: LO              SourceTable: MASTER
Query: D Monthly Loan
    SourceField: HI              SourceTable: MASTER2
QUERY: M FORBEARANCE_1
    SourceField: LOAN-NO         SourceTable: MASTER
```

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk. `grep Source a|awk '{print "Query: D Monthly Loan" $0}'` = `awk '/Source/{print "Query: D Monthly Loan" $0}' a`

Comment: thanks for the hint on `grep` functionality within `awk` @EdMorton